# How can I guarantee the convergence of $f_i(v)$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $f_i:\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^n$ be a sequence of linear functions and let $v_i$ be a convergent sequence with $\lim v_i=v$. Assume that $f_i(v_i)$ is convergent. What assumptions do I need to impose to guarantee $\lim f_i(v)=\lim f_i(v_i)$? It is clear that if $f_i$ is convergent, then the limit is convergent. I'd like to know if there are other conditions.

Comment: Are $v_i$ and $v$ fixed? Or do you want $\lim f_i(v) = \lim f_i(v_i)$ for all convergent sequences $v_i \to v$?

Comment: They are fixed, thanks!

Comment: If the family $(f_i)_{i}$ is equicontinuous? (which is equivalent to $\sup_{i}||f_i||<\infty$)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. May I ask if we need $f_i$ to be equicontinuous globally or just locally?

Comment: @Levent I think that if it is locally then it must be globally by linearity of the $f_i$'s. I suspect that it is the same argument as local continuity implies global continuity when dealing with linear functions.

Comment: That sounds right, thanks.